# Guardar los recursos de una pagina en javafx webview

Tags: javafx

Sucede lo siguiente, he creado un navegador en javafx el cual carga una página, pero siempre que se abre la aplicación se debe esperar a que carguen los recursos (carga lento), existe una manera de que cuando abra por primera vez la aplicación se puedan descargar los recursos para que las siguientes veces que la abra la página cargue más rápido?

Si la pregunta no llegase a ser clara, cuando se carga una página se supone que el navegador descarga los recursos automáticamente, la cosa es saber donde se descargan esos recursos para poder reutilizarlos y de esa forma las siguientes veces que abra el navegador o ejecute la aplicación, la carga sea mas rapida.

Nota: No planeo cargar varias páginas sino una sola.

Este es el código.

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/FXMLWChan.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        stage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
        stage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
        stage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        root.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            xoffset = e.getSceneX();
            yoffset = e.getSceneY();
        });
        root.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            stage.setX(e.getScreenX() - xoffset);
            stage.setY(e.getScreenY() - yoffset);
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO            
        engine = wv.getEngine();
        engine.load("https://www.juegosjuegos.ws/");        
    }
```

Comment: ¿Dónde usas `WebView` en tu código?

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy trabajando en MVC,  wv representa la variable de WebWiew en este caso.

Comment: El navegador y el acceso a la pagina funciona de maravilla, el problema es la demora en la carga, es por ello la pregunta.

Comment: Entiendo. ¿Qué versión tienes de Java? Parece que en algunas versiones ha habido problemas de rendimiento con WebView.

Comment: Estoy usando la versión 8

Comment: ¿Cuál de ellas? En SO en inglés decían que en la versión `8u25` y `8u40` me parece había problemas con WebView.

Comment: Revisa también el Log, para ver si te pone algún tipo de advertencia que de pistas de lo que pueda estar ocurriendo. A veces el Log te dice que tal recurso va lento por un motivo determinado.